# How can I iterate over the test dataset batches?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a question about test the model. I created a model test set using `tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory` following as:

```
batch_size = 32
test_dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    '/content/drive/MyDrive/test',
    image_size = (224, 224),
    batch_size = batch_size,
    shuffle = False
)
```

and I get the output as `Found 150 files belonging to 3 classes.`
After that, I want to iterate over the test dataset batches by using:

```
labels_batch = []
for dataset in test_dataset.unbatch():
  image_batch, label_batch = dataset
  labels = label_batch.numpy()
  labels_batch.append(labels)
```

I understand that, in the structure of **dataset <class 'tuple'>** consist of 2 positions are **image_batch** and **label_batch**, which are **<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>**.
Therefore, **image_batch[0] should mean first image in test_dataset**. When I want to show array of first image, I use the command `print(image_batch[0])` as shown array of all image with `shape=(224, 3)` but I think the size of all images should be `shape=(224,224,3)`.
**So what command do I have to use to access the array of each images?**.

I use TensorFlow version 2.9 in google colab. I'm not sure `test_dataset.unbatch()`.
**Is the problem here or not?**

Answer (score 2):

the `unbatch` method actually returns each individual image, to get a batch iterator that returns a batch on each iteration you should be calling `batch` method instead, or just use the dataset iterator, ie:

```py
for dataset in test_dataset:
```

so in your code `image_batch` is an image of shape (224,224,3), and `image_batch[0]` is an array of shape (224,3), because you sliced the first dimension.

you might want to check the [dataset documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) for description of each method.

Comment: Thank you. I use 'unbatch' and I create 2 list for keep the value from image_batch and label_batch.